# Create a basic contact form that send a mail

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, bootstrap-studio

I have a template for a form already designed (using bootstrap-studio).
I just need to get the data from it and send it as a mail to my email id.
**It would also be great if the page could get redirected to a new one after pressing submit.**

I have already set up the settings.py and am able to send the 'message' part of the form.

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.POST['message']

        send_mail(
            'Contact Form',
            message,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            ['abcd@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False

        )
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

What I need is to be able to send an email with 'message', 'name', 'email',
included in it.

I tried writing

```
message = request.POST['message','name','email']
```

Didn't get expected results.

contact.html:

```
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2 class="text-center">Contact us</h2>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control " type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="14"></textarea></div>
            <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">send </button></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: so you want to get the user input. Email, Name, Message?
please edit the post and add the html form

Comment: check it out now @Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data from form you have to do it invidually.

```
message = request.POST["message"]
name = request.POST["name"]
email = request.POST["email"]
```

Then you can use this data to pass into send_mail() function as arguments.
To redirect to another page after submitting the form, use this logic:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.POST['message']
        name = request.POST["name"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        send_mail(
            'Contact Form',
            message,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            [email,],
            fail_silently=False

        )
        return redirect("/home/")
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

Comment: how do i pass the all three data into send_mail() as arguments??

Comment: @AdityaKakoti 
send_mail() it takes many arguments 
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None)
it's detailed on the [Django documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#send-mail)